# glClear() not working

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a rotating cube bur for some reason I'm having trouble just clearing the screen in OpenGL. I'm using OpenGL with SDL2 to create the window and render out things to the window but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "GL/glew.h"

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_GLContext glContext;

void CreateWindow(SDL_Window* window, SDL_GLContext glContext, const std::string& title, int width, int height) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Window could not be created" << std::endl;
    }
    glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (glContext == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "OpenGL context could not be opened" << std::endl;
    }
    GLuint status = glewInit();
    if (status != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "GLEW could not be initialized" << std::endl;
    }
}
void DestroyWindow() {
    SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void draw() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}

int main() {
    CreateWindow(window, glContext, "Hello", 800, 600);
    draw();
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    DestroyWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

I build and run the program it creates the window, doesn't clear the screen then closes the window after the SDL_Delay(). I'm a little new to OpenGL and would love to know what I'm doing wrong to avoid it in the future. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the relevant code, don't just link to your repo. Thanks.

Comment: It's a kinda long file so I figured I would link it to not bog down the question but I'll post in the code anyway

Comment: In `CreateWindow` function you modify only local copies of variables `window` and `glContext`. Although this should not affect further drawing, program's shutdown will result in errors. By the way, are you sure that error log is empty and OpenGL context was successfully created?

Comment: I mean, I have it set to print errors out to console so if it weren't created I would see it on the console.

Comment: @LoreleiRS: I see it in your code. I am asking if you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No, I get no errors to the console

Comment: @LoreleiRS the minimal amount of change is to make the parameters of `CreateWindow` be `SDL_Window *& window, SDL_GLContext &glContext` instead of `SDL_Window * window, SDL_GLContext glContext` so that they're passed by reference.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the fact that the function `CreateWindow` accepts the `window` by value. You create a window and store it in a *local variable*, while the value of global variable `window` is still undefined. Later, in `draw` function, you call `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window)`, that is, you call `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` with some undefined value.

Looking at your code style, the most simple option would be to remove `window` and `glContext` arguments from `CreateWindow` function and write directly to global variables.

A better C++ solution would be to create a class holding all this variables.